# How to do reverse geocoding in c# classes in asp.net and without using Javascript and html

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-geocoding

I'm getting Longitude and latitude from a GPS device. And now I wanna know the exact location to which these longitude and latitude belongs.

I have no idea how to do it, I have searched over the internet but didn't find any optimal solution to my problem that i'm facing.

I am doing this project in .net 
I can not use HTML and javascript AND I have to do in C# classes

Please help me guys, I'm really stuck at it.

Comment: `I wanna know the exact location` The latitude and longitude from the GPS device tell you the exact location on earth.  What exactly do you want to output?  The nearest city or landmark?  A map of that area?  Something else?

Comment: Can you do API requests? If so, consider this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Guys I found the solution. You just have to download the Google API V3 and Drag and drop couple of classes and then some web form and a web services and then its done. It is a very small code of 6 - 7 lines.

Although, A big thanks to all of you to make an effort and reply to my question. Thank for your help

Comment: Care to share the code solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to:
 - Compute the distance between two sets of coordinates?

- if so, you can use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)
- Find the location on a map?
  Then you will need a map with geo boundaries or some other form of location information in order to be able to snap your point to the map.

Either way, it will probably help to take a look at the following msdn since you are using C#:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631249.aspx